# How to use SequenceInputStream?

Tags: java, io

**Background**

- 1.I was learning the basic grammar of input and output in java.
- 2.But I found that the SequenceInputStream worked strangely.

⚡**Code**

```java
package book1.chapter10;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] box = new byte[50];
        FileInputStream fin1 = new FileInputStream("D:/Workspace/Java/src/book1/chapter10/data1.txt");
        FileInputStream fin2 = new FileInputStream("D:/Workspace/Java/src/book1/chapter10/data2.txt");
        //fin1's content:"learn!".
        //fin2's content:"java!".
        SequenceInputStream finAll = new SequenceInputStream(fin1,fin2);
        System.out.println("available:" + finAll.available());
        //try read ten:
        finAll.read(box,0,10);
        System.out.println("available:" + finAll.available());
        //try read one more:
        int temp = fin1.read();
        System.out.println("available:" + finAll.available());
        //outcome:
        for(byte x: box) {
            if (x != 0) System.out.print(x +",");
        }
        System.out.println(temp == -1);
        //try read ten again!
        byte[] newBox = new byte[50];
        finAll.read(newBox,0,10);
        System.out.println("available:" + finAll.available());
        //outcome:
        for(byte x: newBox) {
            if (x != 0) System.out.print(x +",");
        }
    }
}
```

⚡**outcome**

```
available:6
available:0
available:0
108,101,97,114,110,33,true
available:0
106,97,118,97,33,
```

**Question**

- 1.Why did the method(read) stop when meet EOF?
- 2.How to read the next Stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why did the method(read) stop when meet EOF?**

You might be expecting it to read "learn!java" on the first call to `read`, but that's not what [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) is documented to do (emphasis mine):

> The `read` method of `SequenceInputStream` tries to read the data from the ***current substream***. If it fails to read any characters because the substream has reached the end of the stream, it calls the `close` method of the current substream and begins reading from the next substream.

"Current substream" is the keyword here. It doesn't try to read data from any other substream, but the *current* one. Just after you created the `SequenceInputStream`, the current substream is the first one - `fin1`. The first call to `read` will hence read from `fin1`, and you won't get anything from `fin2`.

The parameterless [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#read()) also says something similar.

> This method tries to read one character from the current substream. If it reaches the end of the stream, it calls the `close` method of the current substream and begins reading from the next substream.

**How to read the next Stream?**

Well, according to the second half of each quote, the `SequenceInputStream` reads from the next stream when it can't read anything from the current stream anymore. In your code, the first call to `finAll.read` read everything in `fin1`, so the second call can't read anything from `fin1` anymore, so it starts reading from `fin2`.

If you want the data that is read to be in the same byte array, just change the offset parameter to the number of bytes read:

```
int bytesRead = finAll.read(box, 0, 10);
finAll.read(box, bytesRead, 10 - bytesRead);
```

Comment: IMO, the javadoc could be worded better to avoid ambiguity. "it calls the close method of the current substream and begins reading from the next substream" could reasonably be interpreted to mean reading the next substream happens within the same call. There's really nothing that states clearly that the current call returns and the subsequent `read` starts at the next substream.

Comment: @sprinter I agree. I only understood what it meant after I experimented with what `read` actually does :D

Comment: same. And even more confusing for me was that I started by trying `transferTo` called on a `SequenceInputStream` which transfers everything from all substreams in order exactly as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the javadoc:

> Reads up to len bytes of data from this input stream into an array of bytes. If len is not zero, the method blocks until at least 1 byte of input is available; otherwise, no bytes are read and 0 is returned.
> The read method of SequenceInputStream tries to read the data from the current substream. If it fails to read any characters because the substream has reached the end of the stream, it calls the close method of the current substream and begins reading from the next substream.

So read will only return characters from the current substream up to EOF. After that a new read is required.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream in1 = new ByteArrayInputStream("Foo".getBytes());
    InputStream in2 = new ByteArrayInputStream("Barbar".getBytes());
    SequenceInputStream seq = new SequenceInputStream(in1, in2);
    read(seq);
    read(seq);
    read(seq);
    System.out.println("avail " + seq.available());
}

private static void read(SequenceInputStream seq) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
    System.out.println("avail " + seq.available() + " read " + seq.read(buffer, 0, 5) + " ");
    System.out.println(new String(buffer));
}
```

Results in:

```
avail 3 read 3 
Foo
avail 0 read 5 
Barba
avail 1 read 1 
r
avail 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same *weird* behaviour and decided to fix it by reimplementing the functionality (in kotlin, converting to java should be easy).

Background: Some libraries (postgres-jdbc in particular) uses a code-block like this to copy data:

```kotlin
val buf = ByteArray(8192)
while (true) {
  val len = stream.read(buf, 0, 8192) 
  // do something with the len bytes

  if (len < 8192) {
    // nothing more to read
    break
  }
}
```

So, here is the *correct* implementation:

```kotlin
package de.elektrowolle.commons.kotlin.streams

import java.io.InputStream


/** Reimplementation of java.io.SequenceInputStream with _correct_ implementation of available(), skip() and read(byte[], int, int)
 * @see java.io.SequenceInputStream
 */
class SequenceInputStream(
    private val stream1: InputStream,
    private val stream2: InputStream
) : InputStream() {

    override fun close() {
        // close both streams. If one fails, the other one is still closed
        // first stream1 is closed
        stream2.use { stream1.use {} }
    }

    override fun read(): Int {
        val charFromStream = stream1.read()
        return if (charFromStream != -1) charFromStream else stream2.read()
    }

    override fun available(): Int {
        return stream1.available() + stream2.available()
    }

    override fun skip(n: Long): Long {
        val skippedBytesFromFirstStream = stream1.skip(n)
        return skippedBytesFromFirstStream + stream2.skip(n - skippedBytesFromFirstStream)
    }

    override fun read(b: ByteArray, off: Int, len: Int): Int {
        // first read len bytes from s1, then read the remaining bytes from s2
        val bytesReadFromFirstStream = stream1.read(b, off, len)
        if (bytesReadFromFirstStream == -1) {
            // nothing read from first stream, read from second stream
            return stream2.read(b, off, len)
        }
        // some bytes read from first stream, read remaining bytes from second stream
        return bytesReadFromFirstStream + stream2.read(
            b,
            off + bytesReadFromFirstStream,
            len - bytesReadFromFirstStream
        )
    }
}
```